# PHP Mail showing error 'page is not working'

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail from gmail account to any other email
But when I try this page is not working error keep showing

I deleted the mail part of code and the page works fine

my code:

```
$from = '<somthing@gmail.com>';
$to = '<anotherthing@gmail.com>';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$body = "How you doooin";

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'something@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'myfrompassword'
    ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}
```

This appears on my error log

```
[05-Nov-2019 13:19:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  ob_start(): function 'callback' not found or invalid function name in /home/arabiancom9/public_html/qrcode/genrator.php on line 26
[05-Nov-2019 13:19:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  ob_start(): failed to create buffer in /home/arabiancom9/public_html/qrcode/genrator.php on line 26
[05-Nov-2019 13:19:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(Net/SMTP.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/arabiancom9/public_html/qrcode/Mail/smtp.php on line 365
[05-Nov-2019 13:19:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'Net/SMTP.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear') in /home/arabiancom9/public_html/qrcode/Mail/smtp.php on line 365
[05-Nov-2019 13:19:20 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Net_SMTP' not found in /home/arabiancom9/public_html/qrcode/Mail/smtp.php:366
Stack trace:
#0 /home/arabiancom9/public_html/qrcode/Mail/smtp.php(271): Mail_smtp->getSMTPObject()
#1 /home/arabiancom9/public_html/qrcode/Mail/smtp.php(258): Mail_smtp->send_or_fail('<ahmedbadreldin...', Array, 'How you doooin')
#2 /home/arabiancom9/public_html/qrcode/genrator.php(103): Mail_smtp->send('<ahmedbadreldin...', Array, 'How you doooin')
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/arabiancom9/public_html/qrcode/Mail/smtp.php on line 366
```

Comment: Check your server error logs for detailed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fatal error mentioned that **Net_SMTP** class is not found
I believe your used library is partially installed/configure

Please check these documents:

[Net_SMTP](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP/download)

[Net_Socket](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Socket/download)

Comment: It's now showing another error Failed to connect socket: Connection refused
and 2 warnings in error log
[05-Nov-2019 13:42:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  ob_start(): function 'callback' not found or invalid function name in /home/arabiancom9/public_html/qrcode/genrator.php on line 26
[05-Nov-2019 13:42:48 UTC] PHP Notice:  ob_start(): failed to create buffer in /home/arabiancom9/public_html/qrcode/genrator.php on line 26

Comment: Its just warning and notice
But mail sent? have you checked?

Comment: Yeah I am not talking about the warnings about this error : Failed to connect socket: Connection refused

Comment: and the mail is not sent